# Why do I get an error TS2339: Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'never'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am developing a simple component "BackToTop"

```js
const BackToTop: React.FC = () => {
  const bttEl = useRef(null);
  function scrollHandler(): void { 
    var bttHtmlEl: HTMLElement | null = bttEl.current;
    // console.log(bttHtmlEl); Element OK!
    if ( bttHtmlEl ) {
      window.pageYOffset > 50 ? bttHtmlEl.classList.remove('is-hide'): bttHtmlEl.classList.add('is-hide');
    } else {
      console.error('BackToTop is null.');
    }
  }
  useEffect( ()=>{
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
      return ()=>{
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
      }        
    }
  )
```

src/components/BackToTop.tsx:54:43 - error TS2339: Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'never'.

54       window.pageYOffset > 50 ? bttHtmlEl.classList.remove('is-hide'): bttHtmlEl.classList.add('is-hide');
                                             ~~~~~~~~~

src/components/BackToTop.tsx:54:82 - error TS2339: Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'never'.

54       window.pageYOffset > 50 ? bttHtmlEl.classList.remove('is-hide'): bttHtmlEl.classList.add('is-hide');
                                                                                    ~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 7):

the solution of the problem

```js
const bttEl = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is telling you that the code block inside the `if` statement will `never` run.

```
const bttEl = useRef(null);
function scrollHandler(): void { 
  var bttHtmlEl: HTMLElement | null = bttEl.current;
  if (bttHtmlEl) {
    // According to the type definitions,
    // this code block will never execute,
    // because useRef(null).current is always null.
  }
}
```

That code block will never run because `useRef(null).current` will always return `null`.

> `useRef` returns a mutable ref object whose `.current` property is initialized to the passed argument (`initialValue`).

In other words, TypeScript is interpreting your code like this:

```
var bttHtmlEl = null;
if (bttHtmlEl) {
  // This code block will never execute.
}
```

Since the code block will never execute, any variable inside that code block will `never` have a value. That's what [the never type represents](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never).

Comment: thanks for the help. the question is that on js this code works ...
I use the useRef example from the official documentation
You can certainly do this const anything = document.createElement('div');
  const bttEl = useRef(anything); , but ...
how to act in such a situation - for the future
and after all write that any valid code on JS is compiled TS

Answer (score 0):

*useRef* is null at start, you need to check node's existence before using it.

```
const anyRefName = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

const doStuff = () => {
    const divNode = anyRefName.current;
    divNode !== null && divNode.classList.add("my-class-name");
}

<div ref={anyRefName}>
...
</div>
```